# Must be connected to a terminal exception in Java while running the command: screen -s

Tags: java, shell, remote-server, gnu-screen

I have an implementation in Java that opens channel's connection and sends a remote commands to there.
The problem I'm having, is that the following command doesn't work when sending it through Java:

```
screen -S 'screen name'
```

The exception I get is:
Must be connected to a terminal.
When I go to the secureCRT to run my remote command manually, it works and creates a new screen.
This code block is standard connection and sending command, and this is where I get the exception:

```
            channel = connection.openChannel("exec");
            channel.setCommand(command);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            InputStream inputStream = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();
            commandOutput.append(IOUtils.readFully(inputStream)); 
            channel.disconnect();
```

Comment: _Yes_, `screen` can't create a new foregrounded session without a TTY, and it isn't expected to -- its documentation says as much.

Comment: ...have you considered telling `screen` you want it to create a detached session, and then telling it to read/write from that session without ever attaching to it? Bottom line, read the docs carefully, and don't ask it to do anything it doesn't support.

Comment: ...that said, if your goal is to run a program in the background and be able to check on it or read its output later, maybe `screen` is not the best choice (it's a _traditional_ choice, but that's from back in the day when there were fewer other options available). Have you looked at `systemd-run`? Note in particular the `--pipe` option; and of course the ability to create named pipes on the filesystem or otherwise roll your own IPC.

Comment: My goal is to create and do actions on screens without opening a new sessions.